# ASP.NET Core publishing to IIS Blank Loading Screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have published asp.net core 1.0 application to IIS version 8.5 as a new website. 
I can only able to see the login page. After the successful login, getting the blank page. perhaps routing is not working perfectly.I don't have any issues running this app on my Dev machine.see my config and startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
        app.UseSession();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
    }

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

Login Controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private StaunchContext _context;
    public LoginController(StaunchContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserDetails users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var exist =await _context.UserDetails.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == users.Email && x.Password == users.Password);
            if ((exist!=null)&& exist.Id > 0)
            {
                TempData["Users"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exist);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Email", exist.Email);
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Search");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("loginerror", "Invalid username or password");
            }
        }
        return View(users);
    }
```

Comment: Are there any network errors in the browser developer tools? (press F12 -> Network tab)

Comment: Can you add the code for the SearchController?

Comment: Are you checking that the user is authenticated in SearchController? Because nothing in the Login post method is indicating the user has authenticated.

Comment: Yes Petre is right with his comment. Show us your Network or JavaScript error from your Browser's developer console

Answer (score 0):

I believe your default route is the login page. If you change it, does that fix the problem?

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
});
```

(make sure to replace Home & Get with your default page)

Comment: It did not help me.my controller is "LoginController" and the action is "Login"

Comment: But what's the controller for your application home page?

Comment: this is happening for the successful logins 
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Search");
home page-SearchController and action is Index

Comment: Are you seeing the correct path in the URL after the successful login? If so, I would guess that the problem is more likely an issue with SearchController  and it's view than with the login.

Comment: no it is showing the landing URL even after the successful login.

Comment: guys thanks for all the help.sorted out the problem.It was Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design issue